# Delete group of cloned rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to delete cloned rows, I got it to delete but it's only deleting one row and not the group of rows.  What I'm trying to do is make the first set not able to delete but once the rows are cloned be able to delete the cloned rows.  Can someone please help me out, I'm still learning javascript and jquery.

Html:

```
<table align="left" id="show2">
<tr>
    <td align="left" colspan="2" align="center">
        <div class="employmentHistory">
            <table width="700px" class="employmentHistoryForm" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <table align="left" style="padding-left: 50px;">
                            <tr class="row">
                                <td class="text-fields" align="right">Drug name (tradename)</td>
                                <td class="text-fields" align="left">
                                    <input class="admin-input" type="text" name="drug_name[]" />
                                    <span
                                        style="cursor: pointer; color: #007FC6; font-weight: bold;"
                                        class="deleteThisRow" value="Delete">Delete</span>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="row2">
                                <td class="text-fields" align="right">Dose value</td>
                                <td class="text-fields" align="left">
                                    <input style="width: 60px;" class="admin-input" type="text" name="dose_value[]" />&nbsp;
                                    <select style="width: 70px;" class="select-input" name="dose[]">
                                        <option selected value="0">Dose</option>
                                        <option value="g">g</option>
                                        <option value="Mg">Mg</option>
                                        <option value="&mu;g">&mu;g</option>
                                        <option value="ml">ml</option>
                                        <option value="Drops">Drops</option>
                                        <option value="Amps">Amps</option>
                                        <option value="Puffs">Puffs</option>
                                    </select>&nbsp;
                                    <select style="width: 95px;" class="select-input" name="frequency[]">
                                        <option selected value="0">Frequency</option>
                                        <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
                                        <option value="Bd">Bd</option>
                                        <option value="Tds">Tds</option>
                                        <option value="Qid">Qid</option>
                                        <option value="4 hourly">4 hourly</option>
                                        <option value="Nocte">Nocte</option>
                                        <option value="Alternate day">Alternate day</option>
                                        <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                                    </select>&nbsp;
                                    <select style="width: 70px;" class="select-input" name="route[]">
                                        <option selected value="0">Route</option>
                                        <option value="PO">PO</option>
                                        <option value="PR">PR</option>
                                        <option value="S/C">S/C</option>
                                        <option value="IM">IM</option>
                                        <option value="IV">IV</option>
                                        <option value="Eyes">Eyes</option>
                                        <option value="Nebs">Nebs</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr class="row4">
                                <td class="text-fields" align="right"></td>
                                <td class="text-fields" align="left">
                                    <input type="radio" name="chronic_l_duration[]" value="Chronic" />Chronic
                                    <br />
                                    <input type="radio" name="chronic_l_duration[]" value="Limited duration" />Limited duration
                                    <br />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="left" colspan="2" style="padding-left: 300px;"><span style="cursor: pointer; color: #007FC6; font-weight: bold;" id="btnAddMore" value="add more">Add another Medication</span>

    </td>
</tr>
```

Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var clonedRow = $('.row').clone().html();
    var appendRow = '<tr class = "row">' + clonedRow + '</tr>';

    $('#btnAddMore').click(function () {
        $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
    });

    $('.deleteThisRow').live('click', function () {
        var rowLength = $('.row').length;

        if (rowLength > 1) {
            deleteRow(this);
        } else {
            $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
            deleteRow(this);
        }
    });

    function deleteRow(currentNode) {
        $(currentNode).parent().parent().remove();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    var clonedRow = $('.row2').clone().html();
    var appendRow = '<tr class = "row2">' + clonedRow + '</tr>';

    $('#btnAddMore').click(function () {
        $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
    });

    $('.deleteThisRow').live('click', function () {
        var rowLength = $('.row2').length;

        if (rowLength > 1) {
            deleteRow(this);
        } else {
            $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
            deleteRow(this);
        }
    });

    function deleteRow(currentNode) {
        $(currentNode).parent().parent().remove();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    var clonedRow = $('.row4').clone().html();
    var appendRow = '<tr class = "row4">' + clonedRow + '</tr>';
    var counter = 0;
    $('#btnAddMore').click(function () {

        $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
        counter++;
        $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last input[type="radio"]').attr('name', 'chronic_l_duration[' + counter + ']');
    });


    $('.deleteThisRow').live('click', function () {
        var rowLength = $('.row4').length;

        if (rowLength > 1) {
            deleteRow(this);
        } else {
            $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
            deleteRow(this);
        }
    });

    function deleteRow(currentNode) {
        $(currentNode).parent().parent().remove();
    }
});
```

I added my code to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eBrTa/3/

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Can not link to fiddle!

Comment: jsfiddle itself seems to be down!

Comment: To remove every row with class row2, why not just $('.row2').remove()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/eBrTa/4/

**JS:-**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var appendRow;

    $('#btnAddMore').click(function () {
        appendRow = $('.myGroup').clone();
        $(appendRow).insertAfter($('.myGroup:last'));
    });

    $('.deleteThisRow').live('click', function () {
        var rowLength = $('.row').length;

        if (rowLength > 1) {
            deleteRow(this);
        } else {
            $('.employmentHistoryForm tr:last').after(appendRow);
            deleteRow(this);
        }
    });

    function deleteRow(currentNode) {
        $(currentNode).closest(".myGroup").remove();
    }
});
```

**HTML:-**

```
<table align="left" id="show2">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="2" align="center">
            <div class="employmentHistory">
                <table width="700px" class="employmentHistoryForm" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left">
                            <table class="myGroup" align="left" style="padding-left: 50px;">
                                <tr class="row">
                                    <td class="text-fields" align="right">Drug name (tradename)</td>
                                    <td class="text-fields" align="left">
                                        <input class="admin-input" type="text" name="drug_name[]" />
                                        <span
                                            style="cursor: pointer; color: #007FC6; font-weight: bold;"
                                            class="deleteThisRow" value="Delete">Delete</span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="row2">
                                    <td class="text-fields" align="right">Dose value</td>
                                    <td class="text-fields" align="left">
                                        <input style="width: 60px;" class="admin-input" type="text" name="dose_value[]" />&nbsp;
                                        <select style="width: 70px;" class="select-input" name="dose[]">
                                            <option selected value="0">Dose</option>
                                            <option value="g">g</option>
                                            <option value="Mg">Mg</option>
                                            <option value="&mu;g">&mu;g</option>
                                            <option value="ml">ml</option>
                                            <option value="Drops">Drops</option>
                                            <option value="Amps">Amps</option>
                                            <option value="Puffs">Puffs</option>
                                        </select>&nbsp;
                                        <select style="width: 95px;" class="select-input" name="frequency[]">
                                            <option selected value="0">Frequency</option>
                                            <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
                                            <option value="Bd">Bd</option>
                                            <option value="Tds">Tds</option>
                                            <option value="Qid">Qid</option>
                                            <option value="4 hourly">4 hourly</option>
                                            <option value="Nocte">Nocte</option>
                                            <option value="Alternate day">Alternate day</option>
                                            <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
                                        </select>&nbsp;
                                        <select style="width: 70px;" class="select-input" name="route[]">
                                            <option selected value="0">Route</option>
                                            <option value="PO">PO</option>
                                            <option value="PR">PR</option>
                                            <option value="S/C">S/C</option>
                                            <option value="IM">IM</option>
                                            <option value="IV">IV</option>
                                            <option value="Eyes">Eyes</option>
                                            <option value="Nebs">Nebs</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="row4">
                                    <td class="text-fields" align="right"></td>
                                    <td class="text-fields" align="left">
                                        <input type="radio" name="chronic_l_duration[]" value="Chronic" />Chronic
                                        <br />
                                        <input type="radio" name="chronic_l_duration[]" value="Limited duration" />Limited duration
                                        <br />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" colspan="2" style="padding-left: 300px;"><span style="cursor: pointer; color: #007FC6; font-weight: bold;" id="btnAddMore" value="add more">Add another Medication</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. The way you did it works but once you clone one group and press the add button again it adds the 2 groups. Looks like it's cloning all the cloned groups again.

Comment: That's the thing it's not working right, is there any way to make it not clone, already cloned groups as it is cloning a already cloned group. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Thanks that's much better, your the best. If you check my original code you'll see I added a line(counter) for the radio buttons so that each radio button has a unique name and not the same name. How would I implement this into your code? Is there a way to not have the delete on the first group?